# Makefile - How to organize and build multiple library versions

Tags: c, makefile, build, msbuild

I am trying to create a build system, but the structure I am supposed to use in unclear.
I've got various library files with their associated includes.
These library files (or modules) may have various versions. So, module1 may have only 1 version, but ModuleN may have 50 versions.
Now my problem is that I am not sure how to organize my tree so that I can build my Library.a package for a given version.

My first thought was to organize my files in the following way:

```
           Libraries                      Includes
               ¦                              ¦
    ----------------------          ----------------------
    ¦          ¦          ¦         ¦          ¦          ¦
   V1.0      V1.1       V1.2       V1.0      V1.1       V1.2
    ¦          ¦          ¦         ¦          ¦          ¦         
 Lib1.c     Lib3.c     Lib2.c     Lib1.h     Lib3.h     Lib2.h   
 Lib2.c                Lib3.c     Lib2.h                Lib3.h
 Lib3.c                           Lib3.h
 Lib4.c                           Lib4.h
```

Now, how would I build my package V1.2, considering it also needs to incorporate the Union of the latest libraries across the entire tree (ie. V1.2 package = V1.0 U V1.1 U V1.2). In this case, it would not be too difficult to define the rules manually, but it will quickly become unmanageable with 100`s of files.

Maybe duplicating unchanged files from a version to the next one in common practice, but it then becomes difficult to know where is what.

Is there a typical approach to this problem?

Comment: You could use Git. Use one branch for each version.

Comment: lol, commits are local, but pushes should be online. If you are using Git locally, you are doing something wrong. Defeats the purpose of backing up your files on a non-local machine!

Comment: @progLearner That's definitely not doing something wrong. You're confusing version control with backup. That's two different things. If you consider an online repo that you push to a backup, then you are doing something wrong. (I do agree though, that if you're not backing up your stuff, you're doing something wrong.)

Comment: Not confused at all. That is why I referred to Commit (which you might want to call "keep" = local backup) Vs Push (online backup)

Comment: Using "I cannot guarantee to be online" as a reason to not use version controlling is doing something VERY wrong. The purpose of Git is version control, not backup. What you're basically saying is "since I cannot backup I might as well skip version control too"

Comment: Git is messy. In all cases, I would like to build any version of the library out of the latest repository (pulled freshly from Git if you like), in one go, without having to do potentially 100's of pulls from Git.

Comment: If you have set up everything in a good way you could do this with `git checkout v1.1; make`

Comment: As I said, I will potentially need to build many versions. Many projects will be using different version of this library. This will only work for one version. I need my makefile to handle the variety, not Git.

Comment: Why would it only work for one version? You checkout the version you want to build and then you build it.

Comment: I don't think I can be any clearer. Many projects using different library versions to be in one repository. I won't create 100 branches in order to support all the project versions. That's not practical.

Comment: I have to ask again, pretty please: how does your example from above look in the filesystem? I still don't grok this, as you are juggling around a bit with your items (is a package a library, or is it a set of libraries, or what?)

Comment: @Vroomfondel. All the .c + associated .h files build into objects. All these objects may have different versions (since they represent modules that may be modified over time). Out of these objects, I want to be able to generate a Library.a (packaged up list of objects), which will have many versions. Now, pointing at the tree (V1.2 for instance), I would like to generate Library.a for that instance, considering the latter will be made out of all the previous/latest (prior and up to V1.2) objects from previous versions.

Comment: Maybe (even quite likely) I have misunderstood the details of what you want to do, but your assumptions about Git have been pretty wrong so far. It is not messy to have a lot of branches. It is extremely easy. Branches in Git are extremely lightweight, since they are nothing more than pointers to commits.

But I think it would be good if you clarified your question a little bit. Try to give a short example of how you're doing it at the moment.

Comment: And membership information is to be deduced from the filesystem? That is, the functionality you want should find `libraryV1.2` to be dependend on `V1.2/Lib2.c V1.2/Lib3.c V1.0/Lib1.c V1.0/Lib4.c` ?

Comment: BTW, typical approach is to support only certain amount of versions in production, i.e. when you build v1.1 once, it is kept as such, or in case of hotfix you build from the sources used to build v1.1 originally, not incorporating all the future patches from v1.2 and later. You sound like you want everything on everything, and yet you don't want to manage the complexity which will be result of such approach. Then it may become difficult, depends how the code is written and how much the versions differ, it may be manageable, or like with general case, not, that's why version support is limited.

Comment: @ Vroomfondel - That is correct.

Comment: @Ped7g. What you are saying makes total sense, but being able to rebuild previous versions is necessary for regressions. And yes, I do need it all :-) Never said it was easy or would not be asking.

Comment: @klutt. All the points I made about Git were correct, you simple just keep on missing the point by ignoring what I say and repeat. You are obvious a big Git fan and would love using it for any sorts of applications, but it does not apply here. And yes I know what branches are and nice and easy it is to switch between branches. But if you understood branches, you would know that by switching you will loose your previous snapshot. So if you start by building a branch (get V1.0), then switch to second branch to build V1.1, you will have lost V1.0. If all cases switching in not what I want here.

Comment: @progLearner I like Git, but I'm not one of those that see it as a general solution to everything. Ironically enough, you seem to be a bigger fanboy since I would never use Git for backup, since pushing to a remote repo is simply a very bad backup solution. If you still claim that "If you are using Git locally, you are doing something wrong." then I'm out of here, because that's as false as it can be. I'm sure there are other methods to achieve what you want than using a version control system, and I hope someone can give you a good advice. Good luck.

Comment: regressions - if you mean hotfixing old build, that's exactly one of the reasons why version control systems were created, that you can check out the old v1.0 sources, fix the bug, and build v1.0.1 without incorporating the other changes from v1.1, which is now completely different. And "lost v1.0" is exactly what you usually *want*, as you are working on v1.1 ... projects using v1.0 library have their v1.0 binary library already compiled, no need to rebuild it every time (or they may even include copy of v1.0 sources, if binary is not wanted). Looks like you want things which others do not.

Comment: Which means, that you will have hard time to find some "typical approach", as typically things are done in opposite way. Maybe rather search for "atypical approach" :). Or figure out your own scheme.

Comment: You really did miss @klutt's point.  He was saying your makefile could  define a `libv1.0.a` target whose build steps were `git checkout "1.0"; OUTDIR=build1.0/ make compile_lib`, and another target `libv1.1.a` whose steps were `git checkout "1.1"; OUTDIR=build1.1/ make compile_lib`, etc.  Your top-level rule can then be `all: libv1.1.a libv1.0.a`This should be done with git tags, not branches.  It is also perfectly fine to use git locally without every saying 'push'.  This is using git for tracking configuration, which is its raison d'etre.

Comment: If you really don't want a CM system for configuration management, you could use copy's overwrite semantics...to build libv1.2 you `cp V1.0/* SRC/`, then `cp V1.1/* SRC/`, then finally `cp V1.2/* SRC`.  This will break if you ever change the structure of your source files or delete an item, but it could be built using a hierarchy of copy rules to reduce copy/paste.  E.g., target `COPYv1.2: COPYv1.1` whose step just copies the v1.2 files on top.

Comment: To make a file, use `fopen()`

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to handle this is with a version control system like Git.  It was designed to handle **exactly** what you're describing.

There were several suggestions in the comments regarding the use of Git to accomplish what you want.  However, you seem to have a misunderstanding of how exactly the files in your library would be stored.

You said in the comments:

> I would like to build any version of the library out of the latest repository (pulled freshly from Git if you like), in one go, without having to do potentially 100's of pulls from Git

And:

> But if you understood branches, you would know that by switching you will loose your previous snapshot. So if you start by building a branch (get V1.0), then switch to second branch to build V1.1, you will have lost V1.0.

Looking at these comments and your sample file structure, this suggests that you think the V1.0 branch would contain `Lib1.c`, `Lib2.c`, `Lib3.c`, and `Lib4.c` while the V1.1 branch would only contain `Lib3.c` and that the V1.2 branch would only contain `Lib2.c` and `Lib3.c`.  That is *not* how Git works.

Here is an example of how you would store these files in Git:

Start by putting the V1.0 files into a directory structure:

```
[dbush@db-centos7 mylib]$ ls -lR
.:
total 0
drwxrwxr-x. 2 dbush dbush 62 Jan 20 10:19 inc
drwxrwxr-x. 2 dbush dbush 62 Jan 20 10:17 src

./inc:
total 16
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dbush dbush 13 Jan 20 10:18 Lib1.h
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dbush dbush 13 Jan 20 10:19 Lib2.h
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dbush dbush 13 Jan 20 10:18 Lib3.h
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dbush dbush 13 Jan 20 10:19 Lib4.h

./src:
total 16
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dbush dbush 62 Jan 20 10:16 Lib1.c
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dbush dbush 62 Jan 20 10:17 Lib2.c
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dbush dbush 62 Jan 20 10:17 Lib3.c
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dbush dbush 62 Jan 20 10:17 Lib4.c
```

Then create a new git repo, add the files, and commit them:

```
[dbush@db-centos7 mylib]$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/dbush/mylib/.git/
[dbush@db-centos7 mylib]$ git add *
[dbush@db-centos7 mylib]$ git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   inc/Lib1.h
#   new file:   inc/Lib2.h
#   new file:   inc/Lib3.h
#   new file:   inc/Lib4.h
#   new file:   src/Lib1.c
#   new file:   src/Lib2.c
#   new file:   src/Lib3.c
#   new file:   src/Lib4.c
#
[dbush@db-centos7 mylib]$ git commit
```

Now you have the version 1.0 files committed, so next we create a tag based on the current version:

```
[dbush@db-centos7 mylib]$ git tag -a -m "version 1.0" V1.0
[dbush@db-centos7 mylib]$ git tag  -l
V1.0
```

Right now, Lib3.c looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void lib3()
{
    printf("lib3 1.0\n");
}
```

Now let's make a change for the 1.1 version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void lib3()
{
    printf("lib3 1.1\n");
}
```

We can see there's a difference between the working copy and the checked in version:

```
[dbush@db-centos7 mylib]$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   src/Lib3.c
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
[dbush@db-centos7 mylib]$ git diff
diff --git a/src/Lib3.c b/src/Lib3.c
index 3593018..12542d9 100644
--- a/src/Lib3.c
+++ b/src/Lib3.c
@@ -2,5 +2,5 @@

 void lib3()
 {
-    printf("lib3 1.0\n");
+    printf("lib3 1.1\n");
 }
```

Then we commit the change:

```
[dbush@db-centos7 mylib]$ git add src/Lib3.c
[dbush@db-centos7 mylib]$ git commit -m "updated Lib3.c for version 1.1"
```

And tag it as version 1.1:

```
[dbush@db-centos7 mylib]$ git tag  -a -m "version 1.1" V1.1
```

Now let's suppose we want to get the 1.0 code to build.  We checkout the tag:

```
[dbush@db-centos7 mylib]$ git checkout V1.0
Note: checking out 'V1.0'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b new_branch_name

HEAD is now at a1ee8c1... initial commit
[dbush@db-centos7 mylib]$ ls -lR
.:
total 0
drwxrwxr-x. 2 dbush dbush 62 Jan 20 10:19 inc
drwxrwxr-x. 2 dbush dbush 62 Jan 20 10:33 src

./inc:
total 16
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dbush dbush 13 Jan 20 10:18 Lib1.h
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dbush dbush 13 Jan 20 10:19 Lib2.h
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dbush dbush 13 Jan 20 10:18 Lib3.h
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dbush dbush 13 Jan 20 10:19 Lib4.h

./src:
total 16
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dbush dbush 62 Jan 20 10:16 Lib1.c
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dbush dbush 62 Jan 20 10:17 Lib2.c
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dbush dbush 62 Jan 20 10:33 Lib3.c
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dbush dbush 62 Jan 20 10:17 Lib4.c
[dbush@db-centos7 mylib]$ cat src/Lib3.c
#include <stdio.h>

void lib3()
{
    printf("lib3 1.0\n");
}
[dbush@db-centos7 mylib]$ cat src/Lib2.c
#include <stdio.h>

void lib2()
{
    printf("lib2 1.0\n");
}
```

You can see that the full source tree is available and that Lib3.c is the 1.0 version, as is Lib2.c.  Now we want to build 1.1, so let's get the 1.1 tag:

```
[dbush@db-centos7 mylib]$ git checkout V1.1
Previous HEAD position was a1ee8c1... initial commit
HEAD is now at 95a429c... updated Lib3.c for version 1.1
[dbush@db-centos7 mylib]$ ls -lR
.:
total 0
drwxrwxr-x. 2 dbush dbush 62 Jan 20 10:19 inc
drwxrwxr-x. 2 dbush dbush 62 Jan 20 10:35 src

./inc:
total 16
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dbush dbush 13 Jan 20 10:18 Lib1.h
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dbush dbush 13 Jan 20 10:19 Lib2.h
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dbush dbush 13 Jan 20 10:18 Lib3.h
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dbush dbush 13 Jan 20 10:19 Lib4.h

./src:
total 16
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dbush dbush 62 Jan 20 10:16 Lib1.c
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dbush dbush 62 Jan 20 10:17 Lib2.c
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dbush dbush 62 Jan 20 10:35 Lib3.c
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dbush dbush 62 Jan 20 10:17 Lib4.c
[dbush@db-centos7 mylib]$ cat src/Lib3.c
#include <stdio.h>

void lib3()
{
    printf("lib3 1.1\n");
}
[dbush@db-centos7 mylib]$ cat src/Lib2.c
#include <stdio.h>

void lib2()
{
    printf("lib2 1.0\n");
}
```

You can see from here that not only is the 1.1 copy of Lib3.c present but also all other files with their V1.0 content.  You don't need to do multiple checkouts and you don't lose any files that weren't updated in the latest commit.

You can follow the above example to set up your repo.  So you would:

- Get the 1.0 files together in the desired directory structure
- Create a new git repo and commit the files
- Tag version 1.0
- Copy in the files changes for version 1.1
- Commit the changed files then tag version 1.1
- Copy in the files changes for version 1.2
- Commit the changed files then tag version 1.2
- Etc...

This also works if you need to *delete* a file when going to a new version.  So for example if in version 1.3 you remove Lib4.c, then you'll see the file when you check out tags 1.0, 1.1, and 1.2, but not when you check out tag 1.3.

So once you have your Git repo set up, all you need to do is checkout a single tag once and you have everything you need.

EDIT:

When it comes time use these files for multiple (possibly concurrent) builds, Git is still a good fit for this.  If you were to keep your proposed folder structure, you would need to know the full history of the files to get the proper versions of each, and you would still want to make a copy of each relevant source file into you "active" build directory so that object files created by one build aren't overwritten by another.  Git will fully manage all of this for you.

Git allows for cloning a local repository, and for performing a minimal clone of a particular branch or tag, that way you only copy what you need and don't grab the entire git history in the processes, so having multiple copies isn't an issue.  You can do this as follows:

```
[dbush@db-centos7 mylib]$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
[dbush@db-centos7 mylib]$ cd ..
[dbush@db-centos7 ~]$ git clone --single-branch --branch V1.0 ./mylib mylib-v1.0
Cloning into 'mylib-v1.0'...
done.
Note: checking out 'a1ee8c1bfdbb20f3e0716212582338371b60d9bc'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b new_branch_name

[dbush@db-centos7 ~]$ cd mylib-v1.0
[dbush@db-centos7 mylib-v1.0]$ git status
# Not currently on any branch.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
[dbush@db-centos7 mylib-v1.0]$ git branch -l
* (no branch)
[dbush@db-centos7 mylib-v1.0]$
```

The `--branch` option says to clone a specific branch or tag, while the `--single-branch` option creates a shallow clone containing just the given tag so that the `.git` directory of the clone isn't huge and can be created quickly.

Comment: I really hate to ruin a well crafted answer but IMHO the original poster was well aware of the working mechanism of `git`. What s/he didn't manage to get across very clear was the use case envisioned for this question: as far as I understood at that time s/he wanted to have all versions of all files accessible *at the same time in more or less the same location without an intermittent git action*. Obviously s/he has to serve an unknown number of project baselines in an ad-hoc fashion - if this came from an optimization or bandwidth or whatever standpoint remained open.

Answer (score 2):

I know that OP said he did not want to use Git, so this answer is more for other people who reads this question.

A very common practice to build an arbitrary version from a repository is to use tags. Tagging is a way to highlight a specific commit. Git supports two types of tags: lightweight and annotated.

Lightweight tags is like a branch. It is just a pointer to a commit. The difference from a branch is that this pointer does not change with new commits. These tags are not recommended for your purpose. They are more for developers during developing. To create a lightweight tag, use this command

```
git tag <name>
```

The other tag type is annotated tags. They contain much more information and are checksummed. These are the ones you want to use for releases. As with commits, you specify a tag message for annotated tags. To create an annotated tag, use this command:

```
git tag -a <name>
```

This will open up an editor where you write a tag message. You can specify a message on command line too with `-m "<message>"`

To view all tags, just use:

```
git tag
```

You can checkout tags the same way you checkout branches:

```
git checkout <tag>
```

Read more about tagging here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging

So what you do is that you create a (preferably annotated) tag for each commit that corresponds to a release. Then, assuming you can build the project by just invoking `make` you can build any version with these two commands:

```
git checkout <tag>
make
```

Note: In the comments above, I was talking about branches. That was temporary confusion on my behalf. It is possible to use branches for this purpose, but tagging is the proper method.